# GSheets AppScript Mailer not working as intended

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a reminder mailer on google sheets using AppScript. When the date for an event comes, the script should mail me with the following data: Name and link.
I referred to this article: https://spreadsheet.dev/birthday-reminder-app-using-google-sheets

I did everything as instructed but im still not receiving mails.

**Here is my code:**

```
function main() {
  // Load the sheet that contains the birthdays.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Dates");

  // Get the last row in the sheet that has data.
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Load data in the first two columns from the second row till the last row. 
  // Remember: The first row has column headers so we don’t want to load it.
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows - 10, 6).getValues();

  // Use a for loop to process each row of data
  for(var index in range) {

    // For each row, get the person’s name and their birthday
    var row = range[index];
    var name = row[0];
    var elink = row[1];
    var birthday = row[5];

    // Check if the person’s birthday is today
    if(isBirthdayToday(birthday)) {
      //If yes, send an email reminder
      emailReminder(name);
    }
  }
}

// Check if a person’s birthday is today
function isBirthdayToday(birthday) {
  // If birthday is a string, convert it to date
  if(typeof birthday === "string")
    birthday = new Date(birthday);
  var today = new Date();
  if((today.getDate() === birthday.getDate()) &&
      (today.getMonth() === birthday.getMonth())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// Function to send the email reminder
function emailReminder(name) {
  var subject = "Reminder: " + name;
  var recipient = "xyz@gmail.com";
  var body = name + " has started." + "More details here: " + elink ;
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

**Spreadsheet:** [Google sheet with data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iAeHYEZYf4M36g7g0Ia-ddS_XmjKy_MSvcQg9B8GwdQ/edit?usp=sharing)

**Please help me resolve it since im a novice**

Answer (score 0):

The changes I made from the sample code that you provided is the given range from `getRange(2, 1, numRows - 10, 6)` to `getRange(2, 1, numRows - 1, 6)`. I have also updated the "`birthday = row[5]`" to `birthday = row[2]` and inserted the function to send the email reminder to  function `main()`.

---

**You can try this code:**

```
function main() {
  // Load the sheet that contains the birthdays.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dates");

  // Get the last row in the sheet that has data.
  var numRows = ss.getLastRow();

  // Load data in the first two columns from the second row till the last row. 
  // Remember: The first row has column headers so we don’t want to load it.
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, numRows - 1, 6).getValues();

  // Use a for loop to process each row of data
  for (var index in range) {

    // For each row, get the person’s name and their birthday
    var row = range[index];
    var name = row[0];
    var caselink = row[1];
    var birthday = row[2]; 
    
    // Check if the person’s birthday is today
    if (isBirthdayToday(birthday)) {
      //If yes, send an email reminder
      emailReminder(name);
    }
  }
  // Function to send the email reminder
  function emailReminder(name) {
    var subject = "CaseCompBot: " + name;
    var recipient = "email@gmail.com";
    var body = name + " has started! FTW!!" + "More details here: " + caselink;
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
  }
}

// Check if a person’s birthday is today
function isBirthdayToday(birthday) {
  // If birthday is a string, convert it to date
  if (typeof birthday === "string")
    birthday = new Date(birthday);
  var today = new Date();
  if ((today.getDate() === birthday.getDate()) &&
    (today.getMonth() === birthday.getMonth())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

### Update:

I've updated the copied sample sheet that you provided to **9/3/2023** and here's the result:

[image]

Please test and let me know if it works!

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: doesnt work. received no emails

Comment: I tried this on my @gmail email address, and it's working fine.  Not sure why it didn't work for you cause I only based it on the provided sample sheet. Have you tried changing the date on your Sheet to today and run the script to see if it works?

Comment: I have updated the my answer and added a screenshot of the email. I only change the date to today and run the script and I receive the email just fine. I hope that helps!